# Service variable assigned data but it is always undefined when accessed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am still new to angular so sorry if my question is a little ...
I created a service that invoke some REST API and I implemented it with promises.
I am currently with this promise return list of data to controller and put it in `$scope`. 
I want that when I receive data in this function also store retrived data to 
service so I don't have to invoke service again if I already have data.

```
app.service("MyService", function ($http, $q) {
 this.OrignalDataFromService = null;
 return {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    ...
    deferred.resolve(data);
    this.OrignalDataFromService = data;
    return deferred.promise;
  }
}
```

Problem with this is that when I access `OrignalDataFromService` from controller it is always `undefined` (in promise I get data it's just service variable that is undefined) why is that?
I don't understand really where should model reside in angular app.
Is it `$scope` variable in controller and services are just here to allow us to get data from somewhere, or should model be inside service (as a variable)?

Comment: Can you show your controller code? How are you accessing the data from service in your controller?

Comment: The code in the question isn't valid JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the fiddler [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5c193ffv/). You will have to expose the variable in which you are keeping the original data.

**Service**

```
myApp.service('myService', function($q) {
  return {
    OrignalDataFromService: null,
    getData: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var data = ["Data-1", "Data-2", "Data-3"]
      deferred.resolve(data);
      this.OrignalDataFromService = data;
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**OrignalDataFromService** is private variable for service, so if you want can access it you need return in object

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579885/javascript-module-pattern-how-do-private-methods-access-modules-scope)

example:

```
 app.service("MyService", function ($http, $q) {
 this.OrignalDataFromService = null;
 return {
    originalData: this.OrignalDataFromService
  }
}
```